# How can I sum up second column in html table using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

There is a table:

```
   <table style="width:920px;" id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td class="cell0 style1"><p style="font-style:italic;">Nazwa produktu</p></td>
         <td class="cell1 style1"><p style="font-style:italic;">Waga [g]</p></td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>banana</td>
          <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>orange</td>
          <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>raspberry</td>
          <td>35</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
         <td class="cell0 style1"><p style="font-weight:bold;">TOTAL</p></td>
         <td class="cell1 style1"><p style="font-weight:bold;"></p></td>
     </tr>
   </tfoot>
   </table>
```

How can I sum up all cells in tbody second column and put the result in tfoot cell also second column?

The table is dynamic. I would like to use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way of doing it:

```js
let sum=$("#tblPotrawySkladniki tbody td:nth-child(2)").get().reduce((a,c)=>
  +$(c).text().replace(",",".")+a,0);
$("#tblPotrawySkladniki tfoot td:nth-child(2)").text(sum);
```

```html
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
   <table id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
   <thead>
  <tr>
     <td class="cell0 style1"><p style="font-style:italic;">Nazwa produktu</p></td>
     <td class="cell1 style1"><p style="font-style:italic;">Waga [g]</p></td>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>banana</td>
      <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>orange</td>
      <td>20,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>raspberry</td>
      <td>35,5</td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
 <tr>
     <td class="cell0 style1"><p style="font-weight:bold;">TOTAL</p></td>
     <td class="cell1 style1"><p style="font-weight:bold;"></p></td>
 </tr>
   </tfoot>
   </table>
```

Instead of `parseInt()` my script makes use of implicit type conversion with the unary `+` operator before `$(c).text()`.

Comment: OK... I got NaN, but I guess this is because I have float like 40,5 instead of 40.5. Where I can put replace(",",".")...?

Comment: Look at my edited answer.

Comment: well... I copied your code into my table... not as simple one as example... and it calculates weird numbers... i.e. if I ad one row with second column value 1,5 calculated value is 22696.5 Any idea why is that?

Comment: if I add second row with cell value 6,0 (sum up should be 7.5 then) calculated number is 22698...

Comment: Well, I can only help you on the basis of the code you share here. Maybe you can add the "real" data you are having the problems with? Create a snippet and make a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is a dynamic table with a few functions and Ajax calls involved... I would not even know how to share it... one question... because I do not understand the way that your solution works... is the way that + operator works also good for text to float conversion? I have numbers in 9,9 and 9,999 formats in the table.

Comment: OK, I think I have found something... your solution searches for tbody not #tblPotrawySkladniki tbody.... I have several tables in the code and I think it sums up all tables... I have to check this... will come back in a few minutes

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, I will edit my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery .each() to cycle through the second td of each row, access the contents of the element using $(this).text(), then add them up as you go.
You should parse the value first so that they will add up as numbers and not concatenate.

```
let values = 0;

jQuery('table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2)').each(function(){

    let value = parseInt($(this).text(),10);

    values += value;

});

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width:920px;" id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell0 style1">
            <p style="font-style:italic;">Nazwa produktu</p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell1 style1">
            <p style="font-style:italic;">Waga [g]</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>banana</td>
        <td> 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>orange</td>
        <td> <span class='price'>20</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>raspberry</td>
        <td> <span class='price'>35</span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><span id="sum"></span></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.price').each(function(i) {
            calculateColumn(i);
        });
    });

    function calculateColumn(index) {
        var total = 0;
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            var value = parseInt($('.price', this).eq(index).text());
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                total += value;
            }
        });
        $('#sum').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).